# How to find files in hdfs recursively that are greater than a particular size (x bytes)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In hdfs i need to recursively check the files and print only those which are greater than 1TB.

Currently i am using the below command and storing the info of the file.And then using java code to print only the files that has size greater than 1 TB

```
hadoop fs -ls -R Path > filesInfo.txt
```

Is there is any direct command that can be used or hadoop file system provides?

Comment: If you're using Java anyway, why not just use the Hadoop FileSystem API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hdfd dfs -du -h -R <path>    >>/tmp/file.txt` to get the size of a file and then delete which is above 1tb.